# SQL nested inner Join on an Approximate date

Tags: sql, date, join, nested

I am hoping someone can help me get this right.
I'm currently running this sql command to get some data into my excel sheet and it is driving me nuts.

I've got 3 tables that I need to combine

- sup = hourly data on supplies
- audit = logging of when things arrived (sup & meters)
- meters = daily data on meters

Here is where I essentially got to before things started spiraling out of control.
I can get sup and aud to merge and I can get meters and aud to merge. Though I cannot select the top meter for the supply in question.

```
SELECT      sup.*, aud.*, meters.*
FROM        SuppliesData AS sup
INNER JOIN  Audit As aud
ON          sup.AuditID = aud.AuditID 
    WHERE   sup.DeviceID = '14365' 
INNER JOIN  (
    SELECT TOP 1
    From    MeterAudit AS meters
    INNER JOIN aud
    ON aud.AuditID=meters.AuditID 
    WHERE meters.DeviceID='14365' AND sup.AuditDate > meters.AuditDate// << I am so confused now...
    ORDER by    aud.AuditDate ASC
    )
ORDER by    aud.AuditDate ASC
```

My apologies for having try and make sense of my mess.

Essentially,
Neither sup nor meters has the AuditDate field. I need to apply an AuditDate field to the supplies and then for each supply grab the closest meter. It is the nesting (as you probably can see) which is currently getting me... All I see for the error I am getting is 'improper syntax around FROM'

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

For references the following code works perfectly fine

```
SELECT  sup.*, aud.*
// -  simply changing SuppliesData to MeterAudit changes everything perfectly.
FROM    SuppliesData AS sup 
INNER JOIN  Audit As aud
ON  sup.AuditID = aud.AuditID 
WHERE DeviceID = '14365' 
ORDER by    aud.AuditDate ASC
```

jc

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT      sup.*, aud.*, meters.*
FROM        SuppliesData AS sup
INNER JOIN  Audit As aud ON  sup.AuditID  = aud.AuditID 
                         AND sup.DeviceID = aud.DeviceID 
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT AuditID, MAX(AuditDate) MaxDate
    From    MeterAudit
    GROUP BY AuditID
) Maxa ON aud.AuditID = maxa.AuditID AND sup.AuditDate = maxa.AuditDate
WHERE   sup.DeviceID = '14365'
```

Comment: I think we need to nest @ the SELECT AuditID, MAX(AuditDate) MaxDate, as MeterAudit does not have the AuditDate, which must be acquired from the Audit.